# How can a breaking change of Flutter SDK handled in a package

Tags: flutter

https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/parent-data-widget-generic-type

I recently noticed this breaking change being planned for `ParentDataWidget`.

If the generic type of `ParentDataWidget` is `RenderObjectWidget` as should be in the current latest v1.12.13+hotfix.8 of the Stable branch, Flutter v1.13.7 and newer versions complain about it.
Is there any workaround to support both versions before and after the breaking change?

---

On v1.12.13+hotfix.8

```dart
class FrogSize extends ParentDataWidget<FrogJar> {
  ...
}
```

After v1.13.7

```dart
class FrogSize extends ParentDataWidget<FrogJarParentData> {
  ...

  @override
  Type get debugTypicalAncestorWidgetClass => FrogJar;
}
```

Comment: can you post the widget code where this is creating problem as then it will be more helpful.

Comment: @Dev [Here](https://github.com/kaboc/flutter_simple_circles/blob/0addcbcd9def7b5424088a09298ef94fd9ba150b/lib/src/container.dart) is one of the files in the package I'm currently developing. Please also see the breaking change page I pasted in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I used dev branch to compile the following code but hope works for your specific version too.

```
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

import 'stack.dart';

class CircleContainer extends ParentDataWidget<CircleStackParentData> { //<== Changed CircleStack to  CircleStackParentData
  const CircleContainer({
    Key key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    @required Widget child,
    this.degree,
    this.distance = 0.0,
    this.rotate = 0.0,
    this.align = Alignment.topLeft,
  })  : assert(width == null || width > 0.0),
        assert(height == null || height > 0.0),
        assert(child != null),
        assert(distance != null),
        assert(rotate != null),
        assert(align != null),
        super(key: key, child: child);

  final double width;
  final double height;
  final double distance;
  final double degree;
  final double rotate;
  final Alignment align;

  @override
  void applyParentData(RenderObject renderObject) {
    assert(renderObject.parentData is StackParentData);
  }

  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    properties.add(DoubleProperty('width', width, defaultValue: null));
    properties.add(DoubleProperty('height', height, defaultValue: null));
  }

  static CircleContainer of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<CircleContainer>();
  }

  @override
  Type get debugTypicalAncestorWidgetClass => CircleStack; //<== New added line
}

//New Added Class
class CircleStackParentData extends ParentData {
   double width;
   double height;
   double distance;
   double degree;
   double rotate;
   Alignment align;
}
```

Comment: There was a error for "flow-control-collections" in two of your dart file in examples. For that i deleted those file. You can search over SO about that error and the actual issue is solved for now.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work on v1.12.13+hotfix.8, which requires the generic type of `ParentDataWidget` to be `RenderObjectWidget`.

Comment: Ok let me check for that specific version

Comment: For me your current code is working after setting `flutter version v1.12.13+hotfix.8`

Comment: Could you explain why your code should work, please? In my environment, lint says, `'CircleStackParentData' doesn't extend 'RenderObjectWidget'. Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'RenderObjectWidget'`. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Do you possibly mean my code (without any change) is working on v1.12.13+hotfix.8? Yes, it works. What I'd like to do is to make my library work on any version without getting affected by the breaking change as I wrote.

Comment: You also have to plan a new version with breaking change. like flutter cached network image created First rc1 then released when the code was changed on stable.So you will run two version latest of now and rc until breaking change arrives on stable flutter version. Check https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image#-changelog-tab-

Comment: When a breaking changes happens and you are using the breaking feature you have to change.

Comment: Well, that's what I've thought as a last resort. I was thinking that there might be some way of avoiding it and it motivated me to ask my first question on SO.